# unable to execute the awk command in python script using subprocess

Tags: python, awk, subprocess

Hi I am trying to move from shell script to python

`awk -F' ' '{print FILENAME " "$2 " " $3 " " $5}' $text| tail -n+4|head -n -2`

while creating subprocess in python, i am getting an error. Can you please where i am going wrong. I tried using the escape character after F.

```
c1 = subprocess.Popen(["awk -F' ' '{print FILENAME " "$2 " " $3 " " $5}' {0} | tail -n+4|head -n -2".format(text)], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output = c1.communicate()
print output
```

Comment: For `c1`, it looks like you want to pass a string rather than a list and use the `shell=True` argument -- Also, if you do that, make sure that you trust the supplier of `venue` _completely_ because you'll be vulnerable to shell injection.  Otherwise, you'll need to construct the shell pipeline in python (which is slightly more cumbersome, but still possible)

Comment: i tried this as well  c1 = subprocess.Popen(['awk', "-F' '", "'{print FILENAME " "$2 " " $3 " " $5}'", {0}].format(text)], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
c2 = subprocess.Popen(['tail', '-n+4'], stdin=c1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
c3 = subprocess.Popen(['head', '-n', '-2'], stdin=c2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output,err = c3.communicate()

Comment: I tried shell=True, i am getting an error KeyError: 'print FILENAME $2  $3  $5 '

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by

first = "awk -F' ' '{print "+venue+" $2 "+"$3 "+"$5}' "+venue1+" | tail -n+4|head -n -2"

c1 = subprocess.Popen([first], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

x= c1.communicate()[0]

the output is 
xyz
i need space in between x, y and z